# QNAP - PHP Script to List directories (Websites) / Web Development

Tags: php, development-environment

I have the following:

- QNAP server which has (MYSQL / PHP)

The IP address of the server is `192.168.1.180`

What I am trying to do:

- To access `http://192.168.1.180` then it will show the PHP file which will have list of all the virtual hosts listed in the same directory.

Example:

```
 1. http://192.168.1.180/index.php (Main page that shows the list of directories)
 2. http://192.168.1.180/dev-website-001 (some website)
 3. http://192.168.1.180/dev-my-shop (some website)
```

The idea of the script is that I only need to put in `192.168.1.180` and select the folder which is the website I am working on. And then I have click on the folder and I have the site up and going.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found which for me is a better idea. Not only can I have a list of all the websites but I can build it into a nice opening web which can contain other information.

```
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script#comment-1628
```

The link above is for the script that I have used and works very well.